# Generate 32-bit Random number in win32 application

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am working on win32 application in **Visual Studio 2010**

I want to generate two 32-bit random numbers which must be greater then 999999, how i can achieve it

Comment: What are you struggling with? Generating random numbers? Generating them in range? Doing so twice? Did you make any effort at all yourself? What language are you using? Or do you need both the tagged languages. Do remember that C and C++ are different.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the C++11 random:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

```
std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t> dist(10000);

std::cout << dist(rd) << std::endl;
```

I don't develop in MSVC++, so I hope it supports these already ;)

Comment: The Standard Library in MSVC++ 2012 is pretty close, the biggest issues are in the core language part. _Again_.

Answer (score 1):

The Rand function return an integer between 0 and RAND_MAX that is guaranteed to a least 32767

so first seed the rand function and call rand.

```
  #include <stdlib.h>

 srand(0);
 long int r = 999999 + (long int)((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX * (LONG_MAX - 999999 + 1))  ;
```

If 999999 is your min value, first scale the rand output between [0;1], now scale to the new range [0; LONG_MAX-999999] and shift to [999999 ; LONG_MAX] by adding 999999 .

Comment: Now how does that get him a 32-bit random int that's larger than 999999?

Comment: Just change the interval